# Como converter tipo DateTime para nvarchar?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, conversão-de-tipo, stored-procedures

Tenho uma tabela com uma coluna do tipo `nvarchar`, e passo o seguinte parâmetro para o *stored procedure*:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PointDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

como previsto, estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Additional information: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.
```

Como faço para converter `DateTime` para `nvarchar`?

Comment: Tem de converter `DateTime.Now` para *string*

Comment: Porque sua coluna é Nvachar? Não poderia ser varchar? Bom ver você aqui no SO.

Comment: E por que você quer converter DateTime pra nvarchar? Por que você não passa este parâmetro assim: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@PointDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom. tudo depende de como você vai usar essa data como String na sua SP.

Converter uma data via ToString vai gerar uma string no formato geral de data longa, cujo resultado final varia de acordo das configurações de idioma da máquina onde a função é rodada (a não ser que a aplicação mude manualmente a cultura OU você utilize uma das sobrecargas de ToString para especificar outro formato). Isso pode ser problemático.

Antes de tudo, você precisa descobrir que formato essa SP espera dessa String.

1) Se ela vai usar o valor para comparar diretamente com um datetime do SQL, então você terá problemas. O melhor seria instanciar um [SqlDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime(v=vs.110).aspx) passando como parâmetro sua data, e então passar como parâmetro para a SP o retorno da função ToSqlString();

```
var sqlDate = new SqlDateTime(DateTime.Now);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PointDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sqlDate.ToSqlString();
```

2) Se ela espera a data num formato específico (dd/MM/aaaa, ou aaaa-mm-dd, etc), então o melhor é passar um ToString(string format) com o formato necessário.
Mais informações de formatos de DateTime [no MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx).